# Running jar via code- Java

Tags: java, jar

```
final String dir = "C:\\Users\\theo\\Desktop\\1.6 test\\craftbukkit.jar";
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime()
    .exec("java -Xmx1024M -jar "+ dir +" -o true PAUSE");
```

So.I did some research around here but this thing apparently is not working/running the JAR file.

Comment: running JAR file? You can run program where main method is entry point.

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the space in the path of the jar. This means, in the command you build up it will be seen as two arguments:

```
java -Xmx1024M -jar C:\Users\theo\Desktop\1.6 test\craftbukkit.jar -o true PAUSE
```

Try to quote the path to build a command like this:

```
java -Xmx1024M -jar "C:\Users\theo\Desktop\1.6 test\craftbukkit.jar" -o true PAUSE
```

Comment: Well, I tried doing this too , renamed the folder and stuff. Seems to work BUT I get no signal that it is working, only the loading sign on mouse

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to provide the full path to the Java executable, not just 'java'.
2. Assuming the program in question is well-behaved, you could use reflection to invoke the `main` method on the jar's main class without starting up a new JVM.

Comment: Full path done . I want background - excecution because i receive iputstream. Now it says unable to access jarfile

Comment: You probably have to protect the space in the path (right now, it looks like `C:\\Users\\theo\\Desktop\\1.6` and `test\\craftbukkit.jar` are separate arguments).

Comment: fixed that too. Now I dont even get an error, nor feedback :)